# Ajax запрос JQuery в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всех с праздником! Помогите перевести Ajax запрос c JQuery на JS

```js
  $('#btn_toggle').on('click', function() {
 $('.catalog li').each(function(i) {
  $(this).toggleClass('list');
 });
 $(this).text(function(i, text) {
  return text == 'variable1' ? 'variable2' : 'variable1';
 });
    });

    $('#btn_more').on('click', function() {  
 console.log(111); 
 $.ajax({
  url: 'ajax_more.php', 
  type: 'post',  
  dataType: 'json',  
  success: function(data) {   
   if (data.result == 'success') {
    $('#catalog').append(data.html);      
   }
  }
 }); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn_toggle">variable1</button>

<ul class="catalog" id="catalog">
  <li>TBD!</li>
</ul>

<button id="btn_more">More</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов перевести Ajax запрос c JQuery на JS

1. Использовать [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), но учтите, что это экспериментальная технология, которая [не поддерживается старыми браузерами](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch).

   Вот пример кода для вашего случая:

   ```
   fetch('ajax_more.php',
       {
           method: 'POST'
       }
   )
   .then(data => data.json())
   .then((data) => {
       if (data.result == 'success') {
           $('#catalog').append(data.html);                        
       }
   })
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
   ```
2. Использовать [XMLHttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp)

   ```
   function ajax(url, success) {
       var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       request.open('POST', url, true);
       request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
       request.send({});
       request.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
               try {
                   var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                   success(data);
               } catch (err) {
                   console.log(err);
               }              
           }
       }
   }

   ajax('ajax_more.php', function (data) {
       if (data.result == 'success') {
           $('#catalog').append(data.html);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Добавьте парсинг JSON в версию с XHR

Comment: @user3127286 точно, спасибо